# This program is for giving the carrier and the country of a specific number , but it's just return the carrier without country

Tags: python, geocoder, python-phonenumber

there is the code :

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder
number = input("enter the number : ")
ch_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, "CH")
print(geocoder.description_for_number(ch_number, "english"))

from phonenumbers import carrier 
service_number= phonenumbers.parse(number , "RO")
print(carrier.name_for_number(service_number , "english"))
```

I can't realise what the problem is !

Comment: Please provide code and not screenshot

Comment: oh thanks , I think is good for now .

Comment: Does it work if you use the abbreviation `EN` instead of `english`?

Comment: Nope, still not working with that abbreviation  .

Answer (score 0):

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested, switching "english" to "en" fixes the issue.

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder, carrier    

number = "+919876543210"  # example input
ch_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, 'CH')
print("Region: " + geocoder.description_for_number(ch_number, "en"))

service_number= phonenumbers.parse(number , 'RO')
print("Carrier: " + carrier.name_for_number(service_number , "en"))
```

Prints:

```
Region: India
Carrier: Airtel
```

Comment: It's worked . And I realized that the problem is in the VPN , when I use the VPN , the program doesn't return the country (my country) , but it return the country of another number (another country) .